# wixtoolset: Component condition is not evaluating as expected on changing MajorUpgrade schedule to afterInstallInitialize

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

**MajorUpgrade** element is scheduled after install finalize in our product's MSI:

```
    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallFinalize" AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.NewerVersionInstalled)" IgnoreRemoveFailure="no"/>
```

There are some folders written by app at runtime that we want to keep on upgrade and only remove on uninstall initiated from Add/Remove programs. So we use this condition: `(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")`.

```
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        ...     
            <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder"
                xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
                <Component Id="CreatePrivateMyAppFolder" Guid="FA1F4375-71DA-4E61-9A02-BE7FD2D4C87D">
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\Product" Name="PrivateFolderMyApp" Type="string" Value="[PrivateDataMyApp]" KeyPath="yes"/>
                </Component>
                <Component Id="RemoveLocalAppDataMyAppUninstall" Guid="*" Transitive="yes">
                    <Condition><![CDATA[(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")]]></Condition>
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\Product" Name="PrivateFolderMyApp" Type="string" Value="[PrivateDataMyApp]" KeyPath="yes"/>
                    <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="PRIVATEMYAPPFOLDER"/>
                </Component>
        <Directory></Directory>
        ...
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

I need to change the `MajorUpgrade` schedule from ***afterInstallFinalize*** to ***afterInstallInitialize*** for some new requirements. I install version 1 with new schedule. Then install versions 2. However during uninstall sequence of version 2, folders written by runtime are being removed.

From logs, both `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` and `REMOVE` properties are set for the uninstall part. Based on that the condition `(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")` should evaluate to false for the component `RemoveLocalAppDataMyAppUninstall`.

```
MSI (s) (C4:58) [22:58:11:060]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
Action 22:58:11: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action start 22:58:11: RemoveExistingProducts.
RemoveExistingProducts: Application: {8F890AE0-BE0A-5ED9-B406-F7459B3390F9}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={70705091-36C8-5619-9E35-73E455CA17F7} CLIENTPROCESSID=4756 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 REMOVE=ALL
....
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:11:076]: Command Line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={70705091-36C8-5619-9E35-73E455CA17F7} CLIENTPROCESSID=4756 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 REMOVE=ALL 
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:11:279]: Dir (target): Key: _PRIVATEMYAPPFOLDER_4    , Object: C:\Users\Windows_10\AppData\Local\MyApp\
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:11:279]: Dir (target): Key: _PRIVATEMYAPPFOLDER_3    , Object: C:\Users\Windows_10\AppData\Local\MyApp\1753de9b-15a7-49b1-8715-f93a967d12e5\
...
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:11:826]: Doing action: InstallValidate
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:11:826]: Component: RemoveLocalAppDataMyAppUninstall; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent
...
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:12:732]: Doing action: RemoveFiles
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:12:919]: Counted 6 foreign folders to be removed.
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:12:919]: Removing foreign folder: C:\Users\Windows_10\AppData\Local\MyApp\1753de9b-15a7-49b1-8715-f93a967d12e5\
MSI (s) (C4:4C) [22:58:12:919]: Removing foreign folder: C:\Users\Windows_10\AppData\Local\MyApp\
```

Any help in understanding why the condition is being applied during uninstall will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Component conditions only affect install and, with the transitive bit set, reinstall. Uninstall isn't affected. `RemoveFolderEx` in WiX v4 has a `Condition` that lets you do what you want to do.